# how to save array object data in redux store

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

i try to store multiple object in redux store on my react native app, but only one object is save, 
i'm new at redux, i try a lot of solutions found on StackOverflow but no one works :/

result i have in my store:

```
"hives": {"hive_id": 12944, "hive_name": null}
```

result i want (or something like that) :

```
 "hives": [
1: {"hive_id": 123, "hive_name": "HelloHive"}, 
2: {"hive_id": 12944, "hive_name": null}]
```

store:

```
const middleware = [thunk]
export const store = createStore(persistedReducer, applyMiddleware(...middleware));
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
```

reducer :

```
const INIT_STATE = {
  hives: [],
}

const hiveReducer = (state = INIT_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
case SET_HIVES:
      return {
        ...state,
        hives: action.payload,
      };
    [...]
```

action creator:

```
export const setHives = hives => {
  return {
    type: SET_HIVES,
    payload: hives,
  };
};
```

action:

```
export const getHives = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get(GET_HIVE_URL, HEADER).then(res => {
      const status = res.data.status;
      const hives = res.data.hives;

      if (status == 'hiveFound') {
        for (let i = 0; i < hives.length; i++) {
          console.log(hives[i]);
          dispatch(setHives(hives[i]));
        }
      }
    });
  };
};
```

and my API send me:

```
 "hives": [
        {
            "hive_id": 123,
            "hive_name": "HelloHive"
        },
        {
            "hive_id": 12944,
            "hive_name": null
        }
    ]
```

and console.log(hives[i]) return :

```
 LOG  {"hive_id": 123, "hive_name": "HelloHive"}
 LOG  {"hive_id": 12944, "hive_name": null}
```

thanks you

Comment: unnecessary dispach in for loop - dispach all hives

Comment: `hives: [...state.hives, action.payload],` isn't it should be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, in your reducer you don't need to use `...state` spread operator, since hives seems to be the only one variable in your state there. And second, you are iterating over each element of hives, therefore you are inputting them one by one thus overwriting the previous one. You are not appending it to array. Here's how you need to change your action:

```
export const getHives = () => {
  return dispatch => {
    axios.get(GET_HIVE_URL, HEADER).then(res => {
      const status = res.data.status;
      const hives = res.data.hives;

      if (status == 'hiveFound') {
          dispatch(setHives(hives));
      }
    });
  };
};
```

This way it will write the whole array into that variable in redux.

Comment: i try and it's better! now my store return 
` "hives": [[Object], [Object]], `

Comment: Yay! Cool! Glad it helped

Answer (score 2):

You can try this below so you can store the whole array. assuming you already have the actions.

## InitialState

```js
export default {
hives:[]
}
```

## HivesReducer

```js
export default function counter(state = initialState.hives, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case Types.SET_HIVES:
      return [...state, action.payload];
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your reducer try this :

```
case SET_HIVES:
      return {
        ...state,
        hives: [...state.hives,action.payload],
      };
    [...]
```

hope it helps. feel free for doubts

Comment: This will not solve the issue, since the error in the code happens much earlier where in action hives[i] is assigned one by one each time. That's why he ends up being with one record every time

Comment: thanks, i try and the console return : 
```
 Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: Invalid attempt to spread non-iterable instance
```
and my store 
` "hives": []`